# Enviar y recibir datos del puerto serie con C#

Tags: c#

Quiero crear un programa en modo consola con el lenguaje F#. Que se pueda enviar datos al puerto serie y recibirlo. Hice uno en C# y quiero adaptarlo a F#. Como no tengo los conocimientos necesarios en F#, pido ayuda.

**Código C#:**

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

namespace Arduino_Consola_cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Título de la ventana.
            Console.Title = "Arduino Consola C#";

            // Tamaño ventana consola.
            Console.WindowWidth = 55; // X. Ancho.
            Console.WindowHeight = 18; // Y. Alto.

            // Cree un nuevo objeto SerialPort con la configuración predeterminada.
            SerialPort Puerto_serie = new SerialPort("COM4");

            Puerto_serie.BaudRate = 115200;
            Puerto_serie.Parity = Parity.None;
            Puerto_serie.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            Puerto_serie.DataBits = 8;
            Puerto_serie.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            Puerto_serie.RtsEnable = true;

            // Establecer los tiempos de espera de lectura / escritura.
            Puerto_serie.ReadTimeout = 500; // Milisegundos.
            Puerto_serie.WriteTimeout = 500;

            // Detecta cualquier dato recibido.
            Puerto_serie.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            Puerto_serie.Open(); // Abrir puerto.

            ConsoleKey tecla;
            Console.WriteLine("Pulse tecla 1 para encender y 2 para apagar:");

            do
            {
                tecla = Console.ReadKey(true).Key; // Espera pulsación de teclas.

                switch (tecla)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.D1: // Tecla 1 del teclado estandar.
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad1: // Tecla 1 del número del pad.
                        byte[] miBuffer1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Luz_ON"); // Codificación ASCII y guarda en la variable array tipo byte.
                        Puerto_serie.Write(miBuffer1, 0, miBuffer1.Length); // Envía los datos del buffer todo su contenido.
                        Console.WriteLine("Comando \"Luz_ON\" enviado."); // Muestra en pantalla comandos enviado.
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                        byte[] miBuffer2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Luz_OFF");
                        Puerto_serie.Write(miBuffer2, 0, miBuffer2.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine("Comando \"Luz_OFF\" enviado.");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Tecla el 1, el 2 y Escape para salir.");
                        break;
                }
            } while (tecla != ConsoleKey.Escape); // Pulsa Escape para salir del menú.

            Console.WriteLine("Presione cualquier tecla para terminar...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey(); // Espera pulsar una tecla cualquiera.
            Puerto_serie.Close(); // Cierra el puerto serie.
        }

        // Detecta cualquier dato entrante.
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string entradaDatos = sp.ReadExisting(); // Almacena los datos recibidos en la variable tipo string.
            Console.WriteLine("Dato recibido desde Arduino: " + entradaDatos); // Muestra en pantalla los datos recibidos.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aquí lo han intentado, pero no se si lo han logrado.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522535/how-to-read-data-from-serial-port-in-r

Comment: Aquí hay un enlace del puerto serie con elenguaje R, si que se puede hacer. El problema es entenderlo, ajjaja.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/serial/serial.pdf
Quiero enviar textos al puerto serie y también ser capaz de recibirlo.
¿Algún ejemplo?